# How to have different colors in a WPF textbox

Tags: .net, textbox, wpf-controls, styling

Is it possible to have a readonly WPF textbox display the first 3 characters one color and the remaining 7 characters a different color. Best example I can give with markdown is 201**103/478**.

The reason the client has asked for this is because stock numbers have the following format YYYYMM/999. 90+% of the time the client refers to the stock number in YMM/999 format. The request is the YYY characters are displayed in light grey and the remaining YMM/999 characters are displayed standard black.

Currently a textbox control is used as the stock number must be able to be copied to the clipboard and allow sorting via a context menu. If another control is more suitable to fulfill the coloring, copy & sort requirements then that solution is acceptable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Vlad lead me in the right direction to come up with the following answer.

```
<TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right">
    <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="Sample"/>
        </ContextMenu>
    </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
    <Span Foreground="Gray"><Run Text="{controls:Binding Path=StockNumberPrefix}"/></Span><Run Text="{controls:Binding Path=ShortStockNumber}" Margin="0"/>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: You can replace the inner `TextBlock` with the more efficient `Run`. (In .NET 4, [`Run.Text`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.run.text.aspx) is a dependency property, so you can bind it to something.)

Comment: @Vlad: I'll take your word for it that Run is more efficient and have updated the code accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you need exactly a `TextBox`? If you could use `TextBlock`, you would be able to put the first 3 characters into a different `Span` (which can have its own `Foreground` brush). This way you won't have the possibility to set the text through bindings, though.

(You can restyle `TextBlock` to look like a `TextBox`, if this matters.)

Comment: Thanks that lead me down the right path to provide my answer.